# jquery ui datepicker dateformat

Tags: jquery, user-interface, datepicker

I gote some problems to get the dateformat right.

After my date field has lost focus I want it to show like:

dd-mm-yyyy but it has to be saved in the database like

yyyy-mm-dd. .

This is what i have so far:

```
$("#birthdate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            altFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' 
             });
```

Now it's shown in the date field like 11/25/2009 (nov 25th 09)
and posted like 11/25/2009

any idea's?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        altField: '#realdate', 
        altFormat:'yy-mm-dd'
    }); 
});
```

```
<input type="text" name="datepicker" value="" id="datepicker">
<input type="hidden" name="realdate" value="" id="realdate">
```

Then use the realdate to get the date when you post.

Comment: What if I have more than one datepicker and I'm using just one jquery selector $("#datepicker1, #datepicker2") to set the datePicker?

Answer (score 2):

MrHus has a good answer but you should just handle it on the backend because this information can be forged via a proxy or many other possibly malicious ways. If you are running PHP, for instance, it would be something like this:

```
<?php
// BTW... you'll want to check for XSS attacks and other vulnerabilities first...
$date = '08/05/1986';//$_REQUEST['datepicker'];
// This is very simple... you should also check if the date is real...
if(preg_match('/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/',$date)) {
    $date_formatted = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
}
// put $date_formatted into database...
?>
```

A combination of our two answers should get you there (mostly) safely.